# Installation error with RDCOMClient in RSTUDIO

Tags: installation

I´m trying to install the RDCOMClient package in rstudio in order to use the R2PPT package to create power point presentations.

I search and the instruction to install RDCOMClient package is:

*install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")*

The problem is that the reposotory webpage is not available anymore.

does anyone know how to install the RDCOMClient or use R2PPT without RDCOMClient package?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can install it from github

https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient

```
library("devtools")
install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')
```

should work.

Comment: I'm getting an error that this requires Rtools. I've installed RTools but then get build errors. (I'm trying to use the new Visual Studio R extension)

Comment: I can't even install Rtools: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)

Comment: Rtools is just a collection of tools like mingw, ... for Windows.
You can obtain it from 
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
and install it via the installer (.exe) file.

Answer (score 14):

To those struggling to install RDCOMClient with the warning:

```
package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

Remember to explicitly set the repo to load from the omegahat source (as opposed to the default CRAN location):

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```

Note the OP used the old website as repo source.

Answer (score 2):

I also could install it from `CRAN` with `R 3.4` but with a computer stuck with `R 3.3.1` I had error:

```
package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

It's undocumented on `CRAN` so I tried OmegaHat and got

```
package ‘RDCOMClient’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

Then I followed @g-grothendieck 's link in this post [this post's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124591/is-rdcomclient-still-available/47270794#47270794) and found a version I could install manually :

http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/

You can find every version there.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game, but have you tried running just:
install.packages("RDCOMClient")
It lives on CRAN in both 32 and 64 bit versions but isn't documented...

Comment: > install.packages("RDCOMClient") 
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/R/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into the same problem, on R 4.0.3, and this worked for me:

```
remotes::install_github("BSchamberger/RDCOMClient", ref = "main")
```