# Is RDCOMClient still available?

Tags: r, ms-word, rdcomclient

I have spent the past several days trying to install `RDCOMClient` in order to integrate R output in MS Word using `R2wd`

Thanks to SO, I was finally able to wrestle `devtools` and other required packages into shape (man, that was way more difficult than it should have been!) but I have not been able to install `RDCOMClient`

The closest I have come is downloading `RDCOMClient_0.93-0.zip` and then receiving the error message

> "Error: package ‘RDCOMClient’ was built before R 3.0.0: please
>   re-install it"

I also received the message

> "package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)"

at one point.

I have tried the omegahat site as well as github and CRAN with no luck.

I am beginning to think the package is no longer available (I wish I had known that days ago!) but still wonder if I am missing something.

If the package is no longer available for version 3.4.0, can you suggest another package with similar functionality? I am looking to write analyses in MS Word and then embed tables, charts and other output from R.

Thanks!

Comment: It used to be on the CRANextra repo at http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/ .  There may be something wrong with that repo.  I have RDCOMClient 0.93.0.2 installed on R 3.4.0 and don't recall doing anything special to install it but that would have been a while ago now.  The maintainer is listed as Duncan Temple Lang <duncan@wald.ucdavis.edu>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation error with RDCOMClient in RSTUDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509029/installation-error-with-rdcomclient-in-rstudio)

Comment: @grothendieck I used your comment as an answer, but as there were several posts and I couldn't link duplicates to a not upvoted question I answered to another one (and many thanks it really saved me).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You need to install Rtools first.
Then you can install RDCOMClient via:

```
remotes::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")
```