# R packages "rcom" & "RDCOMClient" not available in R 3.4.1

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I am using the latest (patched) version of R (3.4.1.) and have been using R2PPT package for some time. Unfortunately, the package doesn't work anymore as rcom & RDCOMClient dependencies don't seem to be available.

The error message is:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  packages ‘rcom’, ‘RDCOMClient’ are not available (for R version 3.4.1 Patched)
```

The same issue was present in the original (unpatched) version of R (3.4.1.)

I'd be grateful for any tips / suggestions

Many thanks,

Joe

Comment: How did you try to install these? These packages don't appear to be on CRAN. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509029/installation-error-with-rdcomclient-in-rstudio

Comment: Hi, it seems to be resolved now - I couldn't install from Omegahat.net so tried downloading binary from there - but that one seems to be out of date (giving me "package written for R< 3.0.0." error). But I found newer binary zip file at http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/

Comment: just found a solution and wrote answer to similar question, marking this as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation error with RDCOMClient in RSTUDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509029/installation-error-with-rdcomclient-in-rstudio)