# Scraping Website with Unchanging URL in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape a series of tables from a website whose URL does not change when I click through the tables in my browser. Each table corresponds to a unique date. The default table is that which corresponds to today's date. I can scroll through past dates in my browser, but can't seem to find a way to do so in R.

Using `library(rvest)` this bit of code will reliably download the table that corresponds to today's date (I'm only interested in the first of the three tables).

```
webad <- "https://official.nba.com/referee-assignments/"
off <- webad %>%
  read_html()  %>%
  html_table()
off <- off[[1]]
```

How can I download the table that corresponds to, say "2022-10-04", to "2022-10-06", or to yesterday?

I've tried to work through it by identifying the node under which the table lies, in the hopes that I could manipulate it to reflect a prior date. However, the following reproduces the same table as above:

```
webad <- "https://official.nba.com/referee-assignments/"
off <- webad %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("#main > div > section:nth-child(1) > article > div > div.dayContent > div > table") %>%
  html_table()
off <- off[[1]]
```

Scrolling through past dates in my browser, I've identified various places in the html that reference the prior date; but I can't seem to change it from R, yet alone get the table I download to reflect a change:

```
webad %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("#main > div > section:nth-child(1) > article > header > div")
```

I've messed around some with `html_form()`, `follow_link()`, and `set_values()` also, but to no avail.

Is there a good way to navigate this particular URL in R?

Comment: `r <- jsonlite::read_json('https://official.nba.com/wp-json/api/v1/get-game-officials?&date=2022-10-06', simplifyVector = T); r$nba$Table$rows`

Comment: Generate dates, apply a custom function using e.g. map then bind the results.

Comment: @QHarr could you please explain how you knew to do it this way? Thanks!

Comment: I selected a different date and monitored the change in web traffic in dev tools (F12) network tab. I could see the request made there for the data. An example blog [here](https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = port)
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()

url <- "https://official.nba.com/referee-assignments/"
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Date <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ref-filters-menu > li > div > button")
web_Obj_Date$clickElement()

web_Obj_Date_Input <- remDr$findElement("id", 'ref-date')
web_Obj_Date_Input$clearElement()
web_Obj_Date_Input$sendKeysToElement(list("2022-10-05"))
web_Obj_Date_Input$doubleclick()

web_Obj_Date <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ref-filters-menu > li > div > button")
web_Obj_Date$clickElement()

web_Obj_Go_Button <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#date-filter")
web_Obj_Go_Button$submitElement()

html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Game                     `Official 1`            `Official 2`         `Official 3`          Alternate
  <chr>                    <chr>                   <chr>                <chr>                 <lgl>    
1 Indiana @ Charlotte      John Goble (#10)        Lauren Holtkamp (#7) Phenizee Ransom (#70) NA       
2 Cleveland @ Philadelphia Marc Davis (#8)         Jacyn Goble (#68)    Tyler Mirkovich (#97) NA       
3 Toronto @ Boston         Josh Tiven (#58)        Matt Boland (#18)    Intae hwang (#96)     NA       
4 Dallas @ Oklahoma City   Courtney Kirkland (#61) Mitchell Ervin (#27) Cheryl Flores (#91)   NA       
5 Phoenix @ L.A. Lakers    Bill Kennedy (#55)      Rodney Mott (#71)    Jenna Reneau (#93)    NA       

[[2]]
# A tibble: 0 x 5
# ... with 5 variables: Game <lgl>, Official 1 <lgl>, Official 2 <lgl>, Official 3 <lgl>, Alternate <lgl>
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names

[[3]]
# A tibble: 0 x 5
# ... with 5 variables: Game <lgl>, Official 1 <lgl>, Official 2 <lgl>, Official 3 <lgl>, Alternate <lgl>
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names

[[4]]
# A tibble: 6 x 7
      S     M     T     W     T     F     S
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
2     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
3     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
4    16    17    18    19    20    21    22
5    23    24    25    26    27    28    29
6    30    31    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error with the RSelenium solution: `Error in chrome_ver(chromecheck[["platform"]], chromever) : 
  version requested doesnt match versions available = 106.0.5249.21,106.0.5249.61,107.0.5304.18`.  If I set `chromever = "106.0.5249.21"` I get: `Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 106
Current browser version is 91.0.4472.101`. Eventually, after `remDr$navigate(url)` I get: `Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE` Is my software outdated?

Comment: You have to install the software chrome driver https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://official.nba.com/referee-assignments/"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()

clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)

web_Obj_Date <- doc$querySelector("#ref-filters-menu > li > div > button")
web_Obj_Date$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)

web_Obj_Date_Input <- doc$GetElementById('ref-date')
web_Obj_Date_Input[["Value"]] <- "2022-10-05"

web_Obj_Go_Button <- doc$querySelector("#date-filter")
web_Obj_Go_Button$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)

html_Content <- doc$Body()$innerHTML()
read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Game                     `Official 1`            `Official 2`         `Official 3`          Alternate
  <chr>                    <chr>                   <chr>                <chr>                 <lgl>    
1 Indiana @ Charlotte      John Goble (#10)        Lauren Holtkamp (#7) Phenizee Ransom (#70) NA       
2 Cleveland @ Philadelphia Marc Davis (#8)         Jacyn Goble (#68)    Tyler Mirkovich (#97) NA       
3 Toronto @ Boston         Josh Tiven (#58)        Matt Boland (#18)    Intae hwang (#96)     NA       
4 Dallas @ Oklahoma City   Courtney Kirkland (#61) Mitchell Ervin (#27) Cheryl Flores (#91)   NA       
5 Phoenix @ L.A. Lakers    Bill Kennedy (#55)      Rodney Mott (#71)    Jenna Reneau (#93)    NA       

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  Game   `Official 1` `Official 2` `Official 3` Alternate   ``    ``   
  <chr>  <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       <chr> <chr>
1 "Game" "Official 1" "Official 2" "Official 3" "Alternate"  NA    NA  
2 "S"    "M"          "T"          "W"          "T"         "F"   "S"  
3 ""     ""           ""           ""           ""          ""    "1"  
4 "2"    "3"          "4"          "5"          "6"         "7"   "8"  
5 "9"    "10"         "11"         "12"         "13"        "14"  "15" 
6 "16"   "17"         "18"         "19"         "20"        "21"  "22" 
7 "23"   "24"         "25"         "26"         "27"        "28"  "29" 
8 "30"   "31"         ""           ""           ""          ""    ""   

[[3]]
# A tibble: 7 x 7
  Game  `Official 1` `Official 2` `Official 3` Alternate ``    ``   
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 "S"   "M"          "T"          "W"          "T"       "F"   "S"  
2 ""    ""           ""           ""           ""        ""    "1"  
3 "2"   "3"          "4"          "5"          "6"       "7"   "8"  
4 "9"   "10"         "11"         "12"         "13"      "14"  "15" 
5 "16"  "17"         "18"         "19"         "20"      "21"  "22" 
6 "23"  "24"         "25"         "26"         "27"      "28"  "29" 
7 "30"  "31"         ""           ""           ""        ""    ""   

[[4]]
# A tibble: 6 x 7
      S     M     T     W     T     F     S
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
2     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
3     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
4    16    17    18    19    20    21    22
5    23    24    25    26    27    28    29
6    30    31    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: I'm having trouble using RDCOMClient. When I install it, I get: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)`. I read (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509029/installation-error-with-rdcomclient-in-rstudio) that I can install it from github using `library("devtools")
install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')` but even after installing `install.packages("devtools")` and restarting my R session, I get: `Error in library(devtools) : there is no package called ‘devtools’` when I load `library(devtools)`. Do I need a newer version of RStudio?

Comment: You have to install the R package devtools. What is the error that you get when you install the R package devtools?

Comment: Also, I suggest you upgrade your version of R by using, for example, R 4.2.1. If you use a recent version of R, you will have less problems to install R packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Docker software (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/), you can consider the following approach with firefox :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
url <- "https://official.nba.com/referee-assignments/"
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Date <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ref-filters-menu > li > div > button")
web_Obj_Date$clickElement()

web_Obj_Date_Input <- remDr$findElement("id", 'ref-date')
web_Obj_Date_Input$clearElement()
web_Obj_Date_Input$sendKeysToElement(list("2022-10-05"))
web_Obj_Date_Input$doubleclick()

web_Obj_Date <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ref-filters-menu > li > div > button")
web_Obj_Date$clickElement()

web_Obj_Go_Button <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#date-filter")
web_Obj_Go_Button$submitElement()

html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Game                     `Official 1`            `Official 2`         `Official 3`          Alternate
  <chr>                    <chr>                   <chr>                <chr>                 <lgl>    
1 Indiana @ Charlotte      John Goble (#10)        Lauren Holtkamp (#7) Phenizee Ransom (#70) NA       
2 Cleveland @ Philadelphia Marc Davis (#8)         Jacyn Goble (#68)    Tyler Mirkovich (#97) NA       
3 Toronto @ Boston         Josh Tiven (#58)        Matt Boland (#18)    Intae hwang (#96)     NA       
4 Dallas @ Oklahoma City   Courtney Kirkland (#61) Mitchell Ervin (#27) Cheryl Flores (#91)   NA       
5 Phoenix @ L.A. Lakers    Bill Kennedy (#55)      Rodney Mott (#71)    Jenna Reneau (#93)    NA       

[[2]]
# A tibble: 0 x 5
# ... with 5 variables: Game <lgl>, Official 1 <lgl>, Official 2 <lgl>, Official 3 <lgl>, Alternate <lgl>
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names

[[3]]
# A tibble: 0 x 5
# ... with 5 variables: Game <lgl>, Official 1 <lgl>, Official 2 <lgl>, Official 3 <lgl>, Alternate <lgl>
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names

[[4]]
# A tibble: 6 x 7
      S     M     T     W     T     F     S
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
2     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
3     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
4    16    17    18    19    20    21    22
5    23    24    25    26    27    28    29
6    30    31    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```